# One IP Address two websites and SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, ssl

I think this question isn't that hard for proefssionals but i'm not the best into web servers.

I have the following scenario:

- one apache web server on RedHat Linux
- one Homepage (normal HTTP)
- one Site on a subdomain which should get an SSL certificate

It will be run all on one external IP and the routing to the Websites should be done depending on the URL the user is typing into the browser.

So how is it possible to implement this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Can you clarify what issues you're having with configuring it?  It's hard for an answer to cover what you need to know without knowing where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Are you talking about the two websites being `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` or two websites being `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com`, both having their SSL version too?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup 2 [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html), 2 that are regular vhosts that listen on port 80, and 1 (with the same ServerName as one of the ones on port 80) [for SSL](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts).

There's several tutorials for [creating vhosts on CentOS/Redhat](http://dev.antoinesolutions.com/apache-server/virtual-host) or [Redhat Enterprise](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-apache-virtualhosts.html) that should point you in the right direction.