# One IP Address two websites and servers SSL

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

All right I have the following:

- ONE External Ip Address.
- TWO websites on their own physical servers (IIS). (They are separate
  and they have to remain that way). No virtual hosts.
- TWO SSL certificates, one for each website

Main website uses the standard external 443 port
Secondary website uses the external port 8443

Example:

- Main Website: https://main.somedomain.com
- Secondary Website: https://remote.somedomain.com

Internally on the LAN I can go to each website, SSL/Certs are correct and fine. I used DNS to point it to the internal ip address.

Externally, https://remote.somedomain.com will go directly to the "main" website unless I use the 8443 port ... https://remote.somedomain.com:8443

But when I use https://remote.somedomain.com:8443 externally the SSL Certificate is wrong. It is actually trying to use the https://main.somedomain.com certificate. Even though I do not have the https://main.somedomain.com certificate on that server.

So what is going on? DO I need to get another External IP Address? Is there a workaround? This [link provides a workaround but I can use a virtual host](https://serverfault.com/questions/382664/one-ip-address-two-websites-and-ssl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running the web servers on their own boxes the easiest thing is to have unique IP's and redirect the TCP connections to the backend servers.  If you want to go the vhost-route you would need to do the SSL termination on one server (like a frontend haproxy) and then hand out the unencrypted streams to the backend IIS servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one public address and 2 physical servers, how is the public address mapped to each server? How is the nat set up?

It sounds like you need this configuration:

```
public ip / dns record
   |
nat/firewall
   |
server1 <---> reverse proxy <---> server2
   |                                 |
website                           website
```

Because if you only have one address, it can only be mapped to one backend server.
The backend servers have private addresses, right?
So you need to send all public access to `server1` and use it as a reverse proxy for `server2`.

If I am wrong, then I probably need more information from you.

Comment: As seen at http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm you can have multiple SSL sites on one IP now.  The browser support looks pretty good.  I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Not on Windows XP or IE6/IE8, but yeah most browsers support it now.

Answer (score -2):

You can do what @chicks proposes, but it will take some time and coffee to configure and test it. Plus it's not a really good solution if you ask me. Better get that extra IP as long as you cannot co-locate the 2 sites in one server. Virtual hosts only work for websites located in the same server.

Comment: I agree that getting the extra IP to have one IP per SSL site is the safest and possibly easiest solution.